# How to make a dropdown autocomplete navigable by keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, frontend, ecmascript-5

Here, I have a nice autocomplete dropdown that, given a city typed by the user, the page will show all possible city-state-country triplets. For example the name Guadalajara would suggest

Guadalajara de Buga, Valle del Cauca Department, Colombia
Guadalajara, Castilla La Mancha, Spain
and
Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico

The code works perfectly from both the backend and the frontend, the only problem left is that the autosuggest drop down menu will only work with the mouse and not with the keyboard. The Up and Down arrow keys will not allow to navigate through the most appropriate choice and pressing esc doesn't cancel the menu.

I tried everything and I have no idea about what is missing to make this work with the keyboard as well. I would like to find a solution with pure vanilla JavaScript and that would involve the least possible changes in the rest of working code. Here the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vanilla Javascript Cities Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div class="title has-text-centered" id="main"></div>
    <section id="form" class="section" onclick="clearCities()">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">Vanilla Cities Javascript</h1>
            <!-- Row for City, State and Country -->
            <div id="location">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <div id="cities-dropdown" class="dropdown">
                            <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                                <input name="cities" id="cities" onkeyup="getCities()" maxlength="50" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a city" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu3" -autocomplete="off" required
                                >
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu3" role="menu">
                                <div id="cities-dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
                                    <!-- content -->
                                    <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
                        </div>
                        &nbsp;<span class="is-size-7 has-text-info">(If your location doesn't appear immediately, try to type slower).</span>
                </div>
                
                <!-- City Field -->
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="city" id="city" class="input" type="text" placeholder="City" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- State Field -->
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="state" id="state" class="input" type="text" placeholder="State" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Country Field -->
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="country" id="country" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Country" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<script>
    
    function getCities(){
        var inputCity = document.getElementById('cities').value;
        const city = changeCase(inputCity);

        if(city.length <= 2){
            return false;
        }

        // Create request to get cities locations
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
        request.open("GET", "/cities/?cityname=" + city);
        request.send();

        // Called when transfer is complete
        function transferComplete(event){
            //alert(event.srcElement.response);
            locations = JSON.parse(event.srcElement.response);
            // Return false if no matching city was found
            if(locations.length == 0){
                return false;
            }

            // Append choices 
            dropContent = document.getElementById('cities-dropdown-content');
            
            dropContent.innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.setAttribute("onclick", "setCity(" + JSON.stringify(locations[i].name) + "," + JSON.stringify(locations[i].state) + "," + JSON.stringify(locations[i].country) + ")");
                link.setAttribute("class", "dropdown-item");
                link.innerHTML = locations[i].name + ", " + locations[i].state.name + ", " + locations[i].country.name
                dropContent.append(link);
            }
            document.getElementById("cities-dropdown").classList.add("is-active");
        }
        // document.getElementById("products-list").innerHTML = html;
    }

    function setCity(city, state, country){
        document.getElementById('cities').value = city+', '+state.name+', '+country.name;
        document.getElementById('city').value = city;
        document.getElementById('state').value = state.name;
        document.getElementById('country').value = country.name;
        document.getElementById('cities-dropdown-content').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("cities-dropdown").classList.remove("is-active");
    }

    function clearCities(){
        document.getElementById('cities-dropdown-content').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("cities-dropdown").classList.remove("is-active");
    }

    function deleteEntry(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('cities').value = '';
    }

    function changeCase(inputCity){
        return inputCity
               .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, function (allMatches, firstMatch, secondMatch) {
                     return firstMatch + " " + secondMatch;
               })
               .toLowerCase()
               .replace(/([ -_]|^)(.)/g, function (allMatches, firstMatch, secondMatch) {
                     return (firstMatch ? " " : "") + secondMatch.toUpperCase();
               }
        );
    }
    var eraser = document.getElementById("clear");
    eraser.addEventListener('click', deleteEntry);
</script>
```

I hope to find the simpler and least invasive solution to complete a code that just have this left.

Comment: The suggestion provided by the existing answer was already tried during several days and doesn't work. I'm seeking for different answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your dropdown and input to the semantic html datalist element:

```html
    <label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
    <input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />
    <datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
      <option value="Chocolate">
      <option value="Coconut">
      <option value="Mint">
      <option value="Strawberry">
      <option value="Vanilla">
    </datalist>
```

Then both search and keyboard accessibility should work more or less out of the box.

If you really don't want to do that, you have to attach event listeners (vanilla js) to the different elements of your dropdown and input field and write a rather long thing to be able to tab or arrow key your way down and up and back into the search field. I would say it's too much work compared to the reward.

Better to use some time to css-animate the datalist so it behaves a bit smoother and style it neatly.

Comment: The presence of a datalist doesn't turn the list into a keyboard navigable list. The divs and the a tags have the same function. At least, it didn't work to me.

Comment: @ionecum It is completely navigable with the keyboard natively. Which browser did you try? I tested this in Chrome/Brave and it works fine.

Comment: Can be tested on MDN here, also creates the instant search for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Probably your example is about a static datalist. But in my case I have a dynamically generated list
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu3" role="menu">
                                <div id="cities-dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

Comment: In summary
<datalist id="dropdown-menu3" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div id="cities-dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
                                    <option class="dropdown-item">
                                </div>
                            </datalist>

doesn't absolutely nothing. The desirable result is to put the focus in the dropdown list each time the user press the up or down arrow key and make a selection by pressing tab or enter. I still didn't find the way to make it work.

Comment: There are no divs in a datalist. Also, you forgot the input field used for the search. The code is above, why not just copy it?

Comment: Because the real code is in my question and it's about cities and countries, not about ice cream flavors. The extra div is necessary for the business logic and I don't see why should I change it just to make a tabindex to work (it doesn't work in any way). The input field is above the code I provide and it's also necessary for the business logic. I tried to turn the drop-down list into a dataset without changing the existing code a lot (I'll surely would not change it a lot) and I don't get any progress. 
I also think that JavaScript is quite flexible to make the logic work with any dom ele.

Comment: Your approach to solving real-world problems is out of touch, I would say beyond hope. Stop wasting other people's time if you don't want any advice.

Comment: A datalist is simply not required to solve this kind of problem. This is a JavaScript problem, a css workaround may help in some simple cases but it only hides the real problem.